# Cant connect AWS Lambda in VPC to MongoDB in EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

**Where I'm at**

1. I have sucessfully set up MongoDB community edition on an EC2 instance and placed it inside a VPC
2. I am not using Atlas, and I don't have a cluster. Just a single EC2 instance running ubuntu with MongoDB installed on it
3. The database works fine, I can connect to it from my windows machine, browse databases etc. I have set up bindings etc.
4. I have also set up a Lambda inside the same VPC.
5. In the Lambda I try to establish a connection using connection string `mongodb+srv://user@ec2-54-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com` Tbh that is a bit of a guess I can't locate much in the way of documentation for this use case
6. I receive error `querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.ec2-54-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

**Help needed**

Is this possible to do, connect a Lambda to a single EC2 instance running mongo db?
If so what connection string to use? Should I be using the elastic IP address instead? etc

Code snippit. I am using NodeJS but I don't think this matters - it just won't connect

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://user@ec2-54-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');

await client.connect()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `+srv` portion of the MongoDB connection URL is wrong. You should only use that if you want the MongoDB client to lookup an `SRV` DNS record to find the actual address and port of the server. You haven't created an SRV record, you are just using the default EC2 instance's DNS name, so the `SRV` lookup is not what you want here.

That's why you are getting that specific error message, because it is trying to do an SRV record lookup, and failing. So remove the `+srv` portion of the URL.

---

Also, make sure you have opened the port in the EC2 instance's security group allowing inbound connections from the Lambda function's security group ID.

And, you may also want to change the `ec2-54-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com` hostname portion of the URL to be just the private IP address of the EC2 instance. You want to make sure Lambda is trying to connect to the EC2 instance's private IP. It won't work if it is trying to connect to the instance's public IP.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So using a connection string of 'mongodb://172.x.x.x' or a connection string of 'mongodb://172.x.x.x:27017'  (where the IP address is the internal IP address) just times out.  I believe I have the security rules correct.  One thing I notice is that my lambda cannot connect to the internet (because it is in a VPC). I'll enable internet connectivity as a troubleshooting step,. Although in theory I guess I shouldn't need to do that as this is all internal network

Comment: Lack of Internet connectivity would not be causing this issue. The whole point of running them both in the same private network is that they don't need to communicate over the Internet. What is the error message now?

Comment: Also, when you run the MongoDB server on the EC2 instance, are you binding it to `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I did get the lambda connected to the internet but that just led me down a rabbit hole without solving anything as you say. So I backed out all my vpc stuff and started again, just with a simple, default vpn. Yes mongo is bound to 0.0.0.0  - I can connect to MongoDB via compass on my remote windows laptop, so I think from a mongo set up pov all is working well

Comment: when I connect with connection string 'mongodb://172.x.x.x' - this being the internal ip address of the EC2 instance, which is in the same vpc as the lambda I do not get an error message, the connection simply times out at the `await client.connect()` line. I have tried a few different connection strings e.g. appending `:27017` but these haven't brought any joy :(

Comment: That sounds like either the security group isn't configured correctly, or the mongoDB service isn't bound to `0.0.0.0`.